# Saving Files from MFC Dialog

Tags: serialization, mfc

buds. I'm trying to save a "block layout". This consists of saving the data of each block, each being a pointer to the CBlock class. So I need to store their properties within a file, so the player can load its layout and play with it. The problem is that I don't know what's the best way to save that data into a text file. I will be needing at least the `BLOCKTYPE` (This being an `enum` I can use to construct the objects from) and the X and Y positions of the Block.

I tried saving my block vector with a `for` but that didn't work at all. So far I have no idea of how I can save and load as well.

This is how I'm trying to save my files currently, but it doesn't work.

```cpp
void CCreateWindow::OnBnClickedButtonSave(){
// TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
if (m_blockLayout.size() > 0)
{
    CString m_filter = TEXT("Super Breakout Maker Files (*.sbm)|*.sbm|All Files (*.*)|*.*||");
    CFile m_saveFile;
    CFileDialog m_fileDlg(FALSE, TEXT(".sbm"), TEXT("mylayout"), OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT, m_filter, NULL, 0, TRUE);
    //CFileDialog m_fileDlg(FALSE, TEXT(".sbm"), TEXT("mylayout"), 0, m_filter);
    if (m_fileDlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        m_saveFile.Open(m_fileDlg.GetFileName(), CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite);
        CArchive m_saveArchive(&m_saveFile, CArchive::store);

        for (int i = 0; i > m_blockLayout.size(); i++)
        {
            m_saveArchive << m_blockLayout[i]->GetBlockType() << m_blockLayout[i]->GetXPosition() << m_blockLayout[i]->GetYPosition();
        }
        m_saveArchive.Close();
        MessageBox(TEXT("Your layout was successfully saved!"), TEXT("Notification"), MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
    m_saveFile.Close();
}
else
{
    MessageBox(TEXT("You can't save an empty layout."), TEXT("Warning"), MB_ICONWARNING);
}}
```

Comment: Question appears to be unrelated to any dialogs. See [Serialization in MFC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/serialization-in-mfc) for relevant information.

Comment: The question topic is unrelated to the question. The question is more about how to store a enum and values as text in a file. For that CArchive is not a good choice.

Comment: If you run this code under a debugger, you'll immediately observe, that the `for` loop is never entered. Apart from that, `CArchive` is meant to be used to write data in a compact, binary format (documented under [Persistent Object Data Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn002-persistent-object-data-format)). Unless you provide your own `CArchive` implementation, the stream will use this format. If you need to write text, use a `CFile` or a Standard C++ file stream object instead.